# How to get foreground application on Android; Excluding Notifications

Tags: android, usagestatsmanager

I am currently using Android `UsageStats` to get the current foreground application in android inside a Service. However, when I get a notification from any app, my app thinks the other app is in the foreground. *"Whew, that was a booger to type"*

Basically, I need a way the get the current foreground application excluding any notifications.

Got it? Thanks!

**EDIT:**

If my request isn't possible with my current method, what are my other options?

Comment: You cannot use `UsageStatsManager` to get the "current foreground application", regardless of notifications. "NOTE: The last few minutes of the event log will be truncated to prevent abuse by applications."

Comment: @CommonsWare Ok, thanks anyways! What do you mean by "event log?"

Comment: I assume that the documentation is referring to the log of usage events that drives the data made available via `UsageStatsManager`. I did not write the documentation, so I cannot say for certain.

Comment: Ok, I will keep that in mind...

Comment: @CommonsWare see my edit

Comment: I sincerely hope that this is finally impossible, for privacy and security reasons.

Comment: @CommonsWare I understand your concern... That is exactly why the concept of a Privacy Policy was created. ;)

Comment: @CommonsWare, the restriction you're referring to is about `UsageEvent`, not `UsageStats`, and it doesn't seem to actually be enforced in Android 5.0 - 9.0 from my testing.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the package name of current application in foreground:

```
    private String isAppOnForeground(Context context) {
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningAppProcessInfo> appProcesses = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
    if (appProcesses == null) {
      return null;
    }

    for (RunningAppProcessInfo appProcess : appProcesses) {
      if (appProcess.importance == RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
        return appProcess.processName;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: Ok so, just to clarify, this excludes notification pop-ups?

Comment: This list only returns the package name of my app. However, after doing a lot of research I've realized that Google is basically shutting down every was to access this data. Your answer is the best so I've marked it accordingly.